# Unable to git svn fetch, with a custom tunnelling scheme, after a branch is created

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to fetch the lastest svn history, where a branch was created. This is what happens:

```
$ g svn fetch
Found possible branch point: svn+xyz://.../trunk => svn+xyz://.../branches/etc, 24743
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/svn/etc) dd98917ae2e94e414a2a70cf7dfb032aadf89d43
Following parent with do_switch
Malformed network data: Malformed network data at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 307
```

Looking near line 307 of `lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm`, I see the comment:

```
# this requires SVN 1.4.3 or later (do_switch didn't work before 1.4.3, and
# svn_ra_reparent didn't work before 1.4)
```

<s>It's fairly likely my company's SVN server is older than 1.4.3 - What can I do to persuade git to fetch this branch?</s> **EDIT:** Nope, we're on 1.4.4. So why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a [bug in git](https://github.com/msysgit/git/pull/58), present only when using custom tunnel schemes.